# Computation tree logic (CTL): Are AG, AF, EG or EF idempotent?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm studying CTL and I got stuck on the following problem:

**Determine if the following operations are idempotent or not: AG, AF, EG or EF.**

I have the following definitions:
*Let M = (S,→,L) be a model for CTL, s in S, φ a CTL
formula. The relation M, s |– φ is defined by structural induction on φ:*

- **M,s |– AG** φ holds iff for all paths s1 →s2 →s3 →...,where s1 equals s,and
  all si along the path, we have M, si |– φ. Mnemonically: for All computation paths beginning in s the property φ holds Globally. Note that ‘along the path’ includes the path’s initial state s.
- **M,s |–  AF** φ holds iff for all paths s1 → s2 → ..., where s1 equals s, there is some si such that M, si |–  φ. Mnemonically: for All computation paths beginning in s there will be some Future state where φ holds.
- **M,s |– EG** φ holds iff there is a path s1 →s2 →s3 →..., where s1 equals s, and for all si along the path, we have M, si |– φ. Mnemonically: there Exists a path beginning in s such that φ holds Globally along the path.
- **M,s |– EF φ** holds iff there is a path s1 →s2 →s3 →..., where s1 equals s, and for some si along the path, we have M, si |– φ. Mnemonically: there Exists a computation path beginning in s such that φ holds in some Future state.

When I just think about idempotency of the different operations, I feel like all of them are idempotent. E.g. If AG x holds, then AG( AG x) should also hold. Because if we know that M,s |–  AG x holds, then x ∈ L(si) for all states i. Then AG( AG x) should obviously also hold.

But how am I supposed to determine/argue more rigorously that eg. AF is idempotent or not? Am I supposed to test them against some kind of generalised model? Figure out a countermodel?

Could someone explain how I should go about this? I feel lost.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the proof rules. The definitions of the operators AG, AF, etc. are sufficient for a rigorous argument. For example, consider AG. Suppose that $\mathcal{M},s\vdash \text{AG}\,\phi$ holds, which by definition means that... [something about the paths]. Now, can you use this definition to show that $\mathcal{M},s\vdash \text{AG}\,(\text{AG}\,\phi)$ also holds?

Comment: Is it possible to argue like this if I want to show that AG p ≡  AG(AG p)?: @frabala


⇒: If AG p holds, then all paths always hold for p. Thus all states in the paths AG p holds which therefore means that AG(AG p) also holds.


⇐: If AG(AG p) holds, then all states in all paths always hold for AG p, thus all states in all paths also hold for p. It therefore follows that AG p holds.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about solving it for the $\mathrm{AG}$ operator (and for the other operators I would proceed similarly).

##### Direction $\mathrm{AG} \Rightarrow \mathrm{AG}\,\mathrm{AG}$:

Suppose that $\mathcal{M},s_0\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,\phi~$ (for ease, I have renamed the initial state from $s$ to $s_0$).
By definition, this means that for every path $s_0\to s_1\to \cdots \to s_n$, it holds that $\mathcal{M},s_i\vdash\phi$, where $i\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$.

Now, we need to show that $\mathcal{M},s_0\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,(\mathrm{AG}\,\phi)$, which means that we need to show that for every path $s_0\to s_1\to \cdots \to s_n$, it holds that $\mathcal{M},s_i\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,\phi$. Again, following the definition, the latter means that for every path $s_i\to\cdots\to s_n$, we need to show that $\mathcal{M},s_j\vdash\phi$, where $i\in\{i,\ldots,n\}$. But, $s_i\to\cdots\to s_n$ is a subpath of $s_0\to \cdots \to s_n$. So, since by assumption $\mathcal{M},s_k\vdash\phi$ holds for any $k\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$, it also holds for any $k\in\{i,\ldots,n\}$. Thus, we have $\mathcal{M},s_0\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,(\mathrm{AG}\,\phi)$.

##### Direction $\mathrm{AG}\,\mathrm{AG} \Rightarrow \mathrm{AG}$:

Suppose that $\mathcal{M},s_0\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,(\mathrm{AG}\,\phi)$. By definition, for every path $s_0\to s_1\to \cdots \to s_n$, it holds that $\mathcal{M},s_i\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,\phi$, where $i\in\{0,\ldots,n\}$.
Since the latter holds for every state on that path, it also holds for the state initial $s_0$. Thus, by setting $i=0$, we get the desideratum, $\mathcal{M},s_0\vdash\mathrm{AG}\,\phi$.